# C# how to restart application with few changes

Tags: c#

i created a graphical simulator with c# using toolboxes and timers. I should repeat the same process 3 times for completing a task. The main problem is that it will last too long for me to repeat the same code 3 times. That's why i need a solution thought i can restart my application but with few changes in it. Before i created a button and wrote Apllication.Restart() but it's just returning the starting position of my app. I need the starting position but with a few materials added in their
thank you.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.  Could you please add more details?

Comment: i created a graphical simulation  between computer and server which is sending a data one and the other is accepting it. All the components i used(CPU,RAM,NICetc.) and also many functions for the animation. the proccesses shoud be repeat 3 times but each time a new component should be added

Comment: You want to change an application that's already compiled?  What then, recompile and re-run with the changes?  You're already complaining that it's slow.  This seems needlessly complicated and a horrible architecture.  I would suggest re-architecting and add the needed functionality with some data store - config file, database, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Why not wrap your task in a function and call it 3 times using different parameters?

Comment: i use many private,public functions and one partial class of my app. I'm not sure if i can put all the staff in one function because it's a long term animation

Comment: furthermore there should be changed some private functions not parameters

Comment: If functions are different then use object oriented principals and overload your functions (you will have to create more than one) with the changes for each iteration.